# What to consider when using a Ruby extension with Rails?

Tags: c++, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to make a C++ extension (that uses external libraries, namely stdlib and OpenCV) for Ruby, then bring that into a Rails project.  Is there anything special I should do to make it compatible for Rails, or better yet, is there a Rails framework that makes writing extensions (especially for C++) easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of Rails you can create gems with C extensions.

I suggest you watch the RailsCast on how to create a gem:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/245-new-gem-with-bundler

And from there check the RubyGems tutorial on how to add C extensions

http://guides.rubygems.org/c-extensions/

I've never done a C++ extension, but EventMachine is built with C++

https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine

Comment: Although your links were helpful, I'm really stuck on the issue of linking external libraries.  My extconf.rb dies at have_library() for any of the opencv libraries.  Should I post it?